# How to load a hierarchical table using a sequence in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a hierarchical table : TREE (ID, PARENT_ID, NAME)

How can this be loaded in sql using a sequence?
In PLSQL we could use variables etc. but I'm wondering if it can be done in SQL.

This obviously won't work, it fails on row 2 because ID = PARENT_ID and I have a check constraint preventing it.

```
insert into tree (TREE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, NULL, 'root');
insert into tree (TREE_SEQ.CURRVAL, TREE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'branch');
```

This works, but I have concerns about concurrency.
It also assumes that the sequence is defined with `INCREMENT BY 1`

```
insert into tree (TREE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, NULL, 'root');
insert into tree (TREE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, TREE_SEQ.CURRVAL - 1, 'branch');
```

Comment: As you're composing INSERT statements manually, how about providing ID and PARENT_ID values manually as well? You didn't specify number of rows that should be inserted. Maybe you could prepare data to be loaded in MS Excel (that's visually OK, you can easily see quite a lot of data) and then load that CSV file into target table using SQL*Loader.

Comment: I guess so, but then I also need to update the sequence so that the next person that uses it doesn't get duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to just use PL/SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_id tree.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tree (ID, PARENT_ID, NAME)
  VALUES (TREE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, NULL, 'root')
  RETURNING id INTO v_id;

  INSERT INTO tree (ID, PARENT_ID, NAME)
  VALUES (TREE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_id, 'branch');
END;
/
```

Which, given the setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TREE (
  ID        NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  PARENT_ID REFERENCES tree(id),
  NAME      VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE tree_seq;
```

Then after the PL/SQL block, the table contains:

| ID | PARENT_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | root |
| 2 | 1 | branch |

---

However, if you create a function to wrap the sequence:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_tree_sequence RETURN TREE.ID%TYPE
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN TREE_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

Then you can use it in an SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO tree (ID, PARENT_ID, NAME)
SELECT id,
       LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM),
       CASE ROWNUM WHEN 1 THEN 'root' ELSE 'branch' END
FROM   (
  SELECT get_tree_sequence() AS id
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
);
```

Then the table now contains:

| ID | PARENT_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | root |
| 2 | 1 | branch |
| 3 | *null* | root |
| 4 | 3 | branch |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wQZfFyZQ)